# Colab giving OOM for allocating 4.29 GB tensor on GPU in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am running a model which allocates [32768,32768] float weight (around 4.29 GB) in its first layer. But it gives an oom error while adding the layer in the sequential model.
This is the output of nvidia-smi before adding layer -
[image]

This is the error -

[image]

And this is the output of nvidia-smi after the error -

[image]

When the Colab GPU is of 13 GB size, why can't it allocate a weight of 4.29 GB?
The other answers on this for e.g., allowing GPU growth doesn't work.

(Note - the GPU and CPU code division in the model creation was originally meant to be on gpu1 and gpu2, but since Colab provides only one GPU, I divided it between CPU and GPU to use RAM from both)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need to specify GPU explicitly in TF/keras - current versions on Colab will use it when it is available. GPU loading usually takes place at `fit` and `predict` times, not at model building - and then you can fine tune memory consumption using batch size.

Please try your code without the `with` blocks.

And please use proper code copy & paste instead of pictures in future.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for code insertion. But it gives an error in the same line without the 'with' statements also.

Comment: I had a broken runtime in the past. Try to "factory reset" the runtime. I don't think the model is overly large, a standard resnet50 from keras.applications is much much larger an works on Colab GPU without much hassle.

You might re-think the number of units in that dense layer though. I don't think such a large dense layer gives you an added benefit. If the data is pictures, consider convolutions and max pooling layers before flatten the input to get features instead of pixels.

Comment: The output I have shown is after factory reset of runtime. Before the error, ~4300 MiB of RAM is allocated to data according to output of nvidia-smi, and then the crash occurs. Wrt the dense layer neurons, I am replicating architecture from a paper.